# How do I get a random number without a repeating pattern in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to generate 3 random numbers which pick a random string from a list (strLabel) but I keep getting the same combinations. Is there any way to stop it repeating the same numbers?

```
 Random r = new Random();
 int iSelect3 = r.Next(0, 35);
 textBox3.Text = strLabel3[iSelect3];
```

I want to use something "more random" as I keep getting the same combinations of numbers, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
 Random r = new Random((int) DateTime.Now.Ticks & 0x0000FFFF);
 Thread.Sleep(20); // Apply an algorithm to differentiate the seed value in each invocation, or call the Thread.Sleep method to ensure that you provide each constructor with a different seed value.
 int iSelect3 = r.Next(0, 35);
 textBox3.Text = strLabel3[iSelect3];
```

> Providing an identical seed value to different Random objects causes each instance to produce identical sequences of random numbers. This is often done when testing apps that rely on random number generators.
>   If your application requires different random number sequences, invoke this constructor repeatedly with different seed values. One way to produce a unique seed value is to make it time-dependent. For example, derive the seed value from the system clock, as the Random() overload does. However, the system clock might not have sufficient resolution to provide different invocations of this constructor with a different seed value. This results in random number generators that generate identical sequences of pseudo-random numbers, as illustrated by the first two Random objects in the following example. To prevent this, apply an algorithm to differentiate the seed value in each invocation, or call the Thread.Sleep method to ensure that you provide each constructor with a different seed value.

You can learn more about **Random** class in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(v=vs.110).aspx)